# changing url from one to another in one second reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, function, react-hooks

React beginner here, learning by coding, i have a project of mine where i have a small problem (this code is somehow near to my real code, cant share real code),

my question how can i have my newSnapshot for under a second to be this:

let newSnapshot =`api/cam/${site.identifier}/`+`${allCams[0].identifier}/snapshot`;

then after it automatically change to this:

let newSnapshot =`api/cam/${site.identifier}/`+`${cam.identifier}/snapshot`;

English is not my mother langugage so could be mistakes, any question just ask me.

```js
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    snapshotUrl: "",
  });

   const updatePreview = () => {

  const allCams=[{identifier: '7-7-7'}]
  const site={identifier: '1-1-1'} 
  const cam={identifier: '0-0-0'} 
  
  let newSnapshot =
        `api/cam/${site.identifier}/` +
        `${cam.identifier}/snapshot`;

  setState({
          ...state,
            snapshotUrl: newSnapshot,
        });

}
```

Comment: any help/advice is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You need a `useEffect` with `setTimeout` inside of it. Also if you are planning to run this `useEffect` with `[allCams, site, cam]` deps array - ensure those values are memoized in some way, with useState or with useMemo, due to you can get an infinite useEffect execution and infinite rerender.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    snapshotUrl: ""
  });

  const updatePreview = () => {
    const allCams = [{ identifier: "7-7-7" }];
    const site = { identifier: "1-1-1" };
    const cam = { identifier: "0-0-0" };

    const snStart = `api/cam/${site.identifier}/${allCams[0].identifier}/snapshot`;
    const snAfter = `api/cam/${site.identifier}/${cam.identifier}/snapshot`;

    setState((currState) => ({ ...currState, snapshotUrl: snStart }));

    setTimeout(() => {
      setState((currState) => ({ ...currState, snapshotUrl: snAfter }));
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{state.snapshotUrl}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={updatePreview}>
        Update
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: my site, allCams,cam those come from redux i'm getting them for example  like this  const cam = useSelector(
    (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.Cam
  );

Comment: @walee then it should work as is, no need to useMemo as in my example

Comment: as you can see i have those inside a function 'updatePreview'  which is inside 'App', so how can i use useEffect, if i cant use useEffect inside 'updatePreview', or can i ?

Comment: @walee oh, sorry, missed that part. I'll update an answer in a few minutes

Comment: @walee Updated the answer, I hope i didnt miss anything this time and this code does what you expect from it. Button is used just to trigger the function you asked about.

Comment: it is changing it for me endlessly

Comment: @walee Sorry, but i have no idea about how can i reproduce your issue. If you can provide more code (about usage, for example) - i can take a look. Or a codesandbox, but let it be the last resort.

Comment: @walee Sorry, with all my experience - i have literally 0 with using testing libraries for react. I upwoted your question, i hope someone will notice it